# How do I transfer large file from client to server using ruby?

Tags: ruby, http, sockets, webserver, webrick

I have webrick based HTTP server running on a windows machine and client on a Linux machine.
I would like to transfer ~2GB file from the my client program (which is not a browser) to the server program.

What all is available in Ruby for this??

Comment: Does you HTTP server have an application/form that you would use to upload this file if your client program was a browser?

Comment: http://www.jedi.be/blog/2009/04/10/rails-and-large-large-file-uploads-looking-at-the-alternatives/

Answer (score 2):

Webrick is pure ruby and not great at streaming in large amounts of data like that.

What I use for this is nginx with the upload module. Nginx handles the upload to disk, then can issue a callback to something (say a rails app) with the original upload params and the path to the file that was just uploaded. Then you can rename/move it on disk, add its path to DB, etc.

Comment: If you are using Apache you can check out mod_porter http://www.therailsway.com/2009/4/23/uploading-files http://modporter.com/